# Sql Join 4 table columns with 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Is possible to use a join with or to do the join only if the values match?

Like I have table GO and that have 4 ID's for employeer:

```
equi_func1_mat
equi_func2_mat
equi_func3_mat
equi_func4_mat
```

and my employeer table is just the id of the user

```
matricula_qt
```

I'm trying to do something like

```
JOIN tb_funcionario func ON go.equi_func1_mat =  func.matricula_qt
OR JOIN tb_funcionario func ON go.equi_func2_mat =  func.matricula_qt
OR JOIN tb_funcionario func ON go.equi_func3_mat =  func.matricula_qt
OR JOIN tb_funcionario func ON go.equi_func4_mat =  func.matricula_qt
```

I tried also this:

```
JOIN tb_funcionario func ON go.equi_func1_mat =  func.matricula_qt
OR go.equi_func2_mat OR go.equi_func3_mat OR go.equi_func4_mat
```

full query working just for one employer:

```
SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(temp.tempoexposicao))) AS soma_tudo,
        temp.cod_go,
    temp.data,
    temp.item,
    temp.equi_func1_mat
FROM(
    SELECT
          prog.cod_go,
          prog.data,
          prog.item,
          prog.tempoexposicao,
          go.equi_func1_mat
    FROM tb_programacao prog
    JOIN tb_go go ON go.cod_go = prog.cod_go
    JOIN tb_funcionario func ON go.equi_func1_mat =  func.matricula_qt
    JOIN tb_horario hora ON func.cod = hora.cod_funcionario
    WHERE go.cod_go = prog.cod_go
    AND prog.data = hora.data
        GROUP BY  prog.data,prog.item) AS temp
```

I didn't found any help in mysql docs or web someone knows if it is possible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem you have when you try to use one of your queries, such as the `or` in the `on` clause?

Comment: in OR, i dont know if that works to match the columms them join

Comment: You can join with the OR, but that might bring you back multiple rows from the sub query for each item (and your group by would eliminate all but one, and which one that is would be undefined). You could use 4 LEFT OUTER JOINs, one on each func and then value of one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this possibly:-

```
SELECT
      prog.cod_go,
      prog.data,
      prog.item,
      SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(temp.tempoexposicao))) AS soma_tudo,
      CASE
        WHEN prog.data = hora1.data
        THEN go.equi_func1_mat
        WHEN prog.data = hora2.data
        THEN go.equi_func2_mat
        WHEN prog.data = hora3.data
        THEN go.equi_func3_mat
        ELSE go.equi_func4_mat
    END AS aFunc
FROM tb_programacao prog
JOIN tb_go go ON go.cod_go = prog.cod_go
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_funcionario func1 ON go.equi_func1_mat =  func1.matricula_qt
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_horario hora1 ON func1.cod = hora1.cod_funcionario
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_funcionario func2 ON go.equi_func2_mat =  func2.matricula_qt
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_horario hora2 ON func2.cod = hora2.cod_funcionario
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_funcionario func3 ON go.equi_func3_mat =  func3.matricula_qt
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_horario hora3 ON func3.cod = hora3.cod_funcionario
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_funcionario func4 ON go.equi_func4_mat =  func4.matricula_qt
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_horario hora4 ON func4.cod = hora4.cod_funcionario
WHERE  prog.data = hora1.data
OR  prog.data = hora2.data
OR  prog.data = hora3.data
OR  prog.data = hora4.data
GROUP BY  prog.cod_go, prog.data, prog.item, aFunc
```

Note this is an untested best guess, as I do not know the layout and real relationships between your tables

Comment: thx kickstart u gave me a idea what i've to do i cant vote or post my solution cuz dont have reputation enought